# Eclipse Luna Google plugin update

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-luna, google-plugin-eclipse

Iam using eclipse luna with google plugin to develop google app engine application. I installed the update for google plugin and my project which was working well is now full of errors. The import statements for JDO and appengine is showing errors like "import javax.jdo cannot be resolved". when i try to run it with the errors it shows:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.
 My project was working perfectly before i update the google plugin.
The version of eclipse and google plugin:
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
Google plugin for eclipse 4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update must have replaced the gae sdk with a newer version.

Go to your project properties > Google > App Engine and make sure a valid sdk version is selected.